# python error :the following arguments are required

Tags: python

i am new to work with python and i want to run this code , but get this error.

code:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
from model import *
import indoor3d_util
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--gpu', type=int, default=0, help='GPU to use [default: GPU 0]')
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=1, help='Batch Size    during training [default: 1]')
parser.add_argument('--num_point', type=int, default=4096, help='Point number [default: 4096]')
parser.add_argument('--model_path', required=True, help='model checkpoint file path')
parser.add_argument('--dump_dir', required=True, help='dump folder path')
parser.add_argument('--output_filelist', required=True, help='TXT filename, filelist, each line is an output for a room')
parser.add_argument('--room_data_filelist', required=True, help='TXT filename, filelist, each line is a test room data label file.')
parser.add_argument('--no_clutter', action='store_true', help='If true, donot count the clutter class')
parser.add_argument('--visu', action='store_true', help='Whether to output OBJ file for prediction visualization.')
FLAGS = parser.parse_args()
```

what should i do?
error :

```
batch_test.py: error: the following arguments are required: --model_path, --dump_dir, --output_filelist, --room_data_filelist
```

Comment: You set `required=True`, are you giving these arguments when compiling?

Comment: The error is self-explaining. You need to add listed arguments to the script

Answer (score 2):

Those arguments are defined as required in your code `required=True` but don't have a default specified.  You can either specify them at runtime or you can add a default value or you can make them not required with `required=False`

If you need additional help with any of those options, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should see something like:

```
   usage: batch_test.py [-h] [--gpu GPU] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE]
                     [--num_point NUM_POINT] --model_path MODEL_PATH
                     --dump_dir DUMP_DIR --output_filelist OUTPUT_FILELIST
                     --room_data_filelist ROOM_DATA_FILELIST [--no_clutter]
                     [--visu]
```

And just append the arguments from command line, e.g.

```
python batch_test.py --model_path PATH_TO_YOUR_MODEL, --dump_dir YOUR_DUMP_DIR, --output_filelist OUT_LIST, --room_data_filelist ROOM_DATA_LIST
```

Or turn off the **required** from your source code.

Answer (score 0):

When running the python script you showed, you have to include the arguments that are required (which has `required=True`) in the following format:

`python batch_test.py <argument 1> <argument 1 value> <argument 2> <argument 2 value> ...`

In the code you showed, there are several arguments that are required, which are:`--model-path`, `--dump_dir`, `--output_filelist`, `--room_data_filelist`.

You can actually see the instruction on how to fill each argument by entering the command:

`python batch_test.py -h`

Comment: thank you. i write this ( python D:\sem_seg\batch_test.py --model_path log6/model.ckpt --dump_dir log6/dump --output_filelist log6/output_filelist.txt --room_data_filelist meta/area6_data_label.txt --visu) in the command line, but "syntax error" was shown. how to solve it?

Comment: Could you post the complete error message or maybe a link to the screenshot of the output? Syntax errors usually print out the line where the error occurs so it will be easier to trace the problem.

Comment: Btw are you running the script in this URL https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/sem_seg/batch_inference.py? It looks very similar to the code you posted here.

Comment: yes it is.i am trying to run this code but this error occurs.when i copy above text to the command window,"syntax error" was shown and (:) mark becomes red.

Comment: Try entering the command `cd D:\sem_seg\ & python batch_test.py --model_path log6/model.ckpt --dump_dir log6/dump --output_filelist log6/output_filelist.txt --room_data_filelist meta/area6_data_label.txt --visu` to direct your command prompt to the `sem_seg` folder before running the `batch_test.py` script. It might be because python consider the colon in `D:\` is an invalid syntax.